# math game difficulty setting

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make simple math game that has adding right now, I want to add difficulties that so i can choose if i want numbers from 1-10 or 10-20, im using random for it. everything is console sided and i can write numbers for difficulties.

```
    Random numberGenerator = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine("what what difficulty you want?");
    Console.WriteLine("1 for 1-10\n2 for 10-20\n3 for 15-40");
    Console.Write("i want:");
    int hardness = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (hardness == 1)
    {
        goto hardness1;
    }

hardness1:
    int num01 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 11);
    int num02 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 11);
    int num03 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 11);
    int num04 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 11);
    if (answer == 1) {
        goto startofadding;
    }

hardness2:
    int num01 = numberGenerator.Next(10, 21)
    int num02 = numberGenerator.Next(10, 21)
    int num03 = numberGenerator.Next(10, 21)
    int num04 = numberGenerator.Next(10, 21)
    if (answer == 1)
    {
        goto startofadding;
    }

startofadding:
    Console.WriteLine("num01 = " + num01 + " and num02 = " + num02 + " this is " + i + " loop ");
    Console.WriteLine("answer is " + (num01 + num02));

    Console.WriteLine("what is " + num01 + " + " + num02 + " ?");
    Console.Write("Answer is: ");
    int answer1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (answer1 == num01 + num02)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("correct answer");
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
```

I'm trying to use gotos so if the difficulty is chosen it can take numbers that it needs but it gives me:

> A local variable or function named 'num01' is already defined in scope

error, I get what it is, but I don't know how to fix it. Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to make it? ask for more details and more code if something is unclear, tried to explain it as good as i can

Comment: _I'm trying to use gotos_ I stopped reading.

Comment: `goto` is absolutely wrong, you have no concept of variable scopes, and the code is pretty horrific. I'd suggest a C# tutorial.

Comment: tip: consider switching `goto` with `switch` :)

Comment: im beginner and its only way I found that I can make it, im not sure what I look for so I can't really find another way around to make it. any suggestions what i could use other than goto that will make code better?

Comment: @gldraphael The gotos aren't emulating a switch, they're emulating *methods*.  Rather than having named methods, the code is all in one method with labels above each "logical" method, and rather than calling a method, it does a goto to the label, with each pseudomethod always having a goto at the end to the next pseudomethod to call.

Comment: We can't tutor you here. There is far too much wrong with that code. As I said before, find a C# tutorial or buy a book, so you can grasp the basic concepts like variable scopes and program structure.

Comment: @Servy yes, but in this case he can get away with a switch for the hardness labels. (Because he has a if condition to decide which label to goto.) Infact he could remove that and use hardness as a multiplication factor.

Comment: You could also change your ranges to use a mathematical formula that would produce your min/max ranges for the random numbers. This way you ask for the difficulty level (1 to 3) and take that value and perform a calculation that would give you various ranges. To keep 1 as a starting min for easy, an inline IF statement could be used so as not to screw up your normal formula. This would alleviate the switch because you're using the difficulty number to create your random ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A local variable or function named 'num01' is already defined in scope

You've already defined `num01` it under the `hardness1` label.

You can fix it by declaring the variable just once. Don't re-declare the same variables under the next label since it's in the same block scope.

---

Once you get it working, get rid of `goto`. A switch statement is probably the easiest way in this case.

You can replace the if conditions and the `hardness0x` blocks with:

```
switch(hardness)
{
    case 1:
    // code for hardness 1
    break;
    case 2:
    // code for hardness 2... etc.
    break;
}

// Code under startofadding follows. No need for goto or goto-labels
```

---

You next step would be to try and get rid of the switch statement altogether, which will simplify your code a great deal.

Comment: switch seems to work but now my num01 won't get recognized, if I have for example num01, my line what asks the question doesn't find num01.
I don't know if I did something wrong again but I added my random number generator under case 1.
error i get is : "the name 'num01' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @KarlisSaarna Have you learnt to debug yet? If not, try starting from scratch, but write only a few lines of code and then build and check the output if things are fine. Keep adding code little by little.

Comment: I've tried to fix things and so far I've gotten things fixed cause I haven't really done a whole much, even right now im trying to look for a way that I could make my switch and question into 1 context or just somehow make them work together, any info about why they aren't working together is really appreciated.

Comment: If I read your comment right, looks like you need to declare your 5 variables outside the current scope (outside the switch statement). Why? Because you want to access it from outside.

Comment: I think I've got an idea how I'm supposed to do it but I can't seem to find a code for changing num01 when case 1 happens, am I going right direction and does the code exist to change a value of num01 when case 1 is used?

Comment: @KarlisSaarna Just assign a value like you normally do. Declare `num1` outside the switch block. In each switch case assign `num1 = <your code here>;`. Since only one of the cases will be executed, num1 will have the expected value.

Comment: everything works now, really appreciate all the effort you did to help me

Comment: @KarlisSaarna remember to pay it forward when you can :)

Comment: @KarlisSaarna, if you get a chance, google `Bob Tabor C# Fundamentals` it's a beginners C# video series and I think you would benefit from it. He is very good at explaining what he's doing and they're easy to follow along with. While I don't recommend it, he has them sectioned off where you can jump right into things like loops, lists, classes, etc...